# Executing mysql query inside loop

Tags: node.js

I have table emp_details in mysql. im trying to update/insert based on select query execution inside for loop.
if the select return a value -> i will update
if not then insert a value.here is my sample working code.i found an issue when the request has duplicate name,email_id,password.

```
var config = require('./mysql_db');
var connection= config.connection;
exports.insert_data = function(req,res){
var json = JSON.stringify(req.body);
var json_par = JSON.parse(json);
for( let i = 0; i < json_par.data.length; i++ )
{
    sql = "SELECT * FROM emp_details where email_id = ?";
    connection.query(sql,[json_par.data[ i ].email_id],function(error,results,filelds){
    if(error) throw err;
    if(results.length >0)
    {
      sql = 'UPDATE emp_details SET password = ?, name = ? where email_id = ?';
      connection.query(sql, [ json_par.data[ i ].password,  json_par.data[ i ].name,  json_par.data[ i ].email_id ],function(error,results1,filelds){
      if(error) throw err;
      });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("insert called");
        sql = 'INSERT INTO emp_details VALUES ( ?,?,? )';
        connection.query(sql,[ json_par.data[ i ].name,  json_par.data[ i ].email_id, json_par.data[ i ].password ],function(error,results1,filelds){
        if(error) throw err;
        });
    }
});
}
res.end("success");
}


For eg:
{
    "data" : [
        {
            "name" : "scott",
            "email_id": "scott95",
            "password": "scott@123"
        },
        {
            "name" : "scott",
            "email_id": "scott95",
            "password": "scott@123"
        }
    ]
}
```

In this case it's getting inserted both the time.

which i dont want in my case.i want insert query to execute for first loop and then update  query for secound loop.